Adapter recycler view with how can I solve
When I write recyclerview in adapter they showing me error Recyclerview.Adapter(){} In this Recyclerview showing error any body help me how can I solve this because earlier when I use recyclerview they not give any error but now why they showing error I am very confused
I expecting senior developer help me and give advice how can I fix it

what is error include your error in post
